# Ongoing issues with Pinnacle Entertainment Group's forums

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

So Pinnacle Entertainment Group, the company behind Savage Worlds have forums that ordinarily house official answers and clarifications to rules written by Clint Black. These are generally regarded by the Savage Worlds community as RAW.

However, for what seems like many months now the forums have been down. There is a progress message when you try to access them indicating they trying to upgrade the forum, but that message is now over a month out of date, and there's no indication as to when the ongoing problems with them are going to be resolved.

This is a problem on this site as a quite a few answers to questions about Savage Worlds directly link to official posts on the forums as evidence. Whilst the forum is down, these links are broken and useless.

What do we do here? Given there is no indication of when the problems with their forums are going to be resolved, is there an interim measure we can put in place? Something more permanent we should do?

Comment: Among other things (though not particularly helpful for the current problem you're pointing out) we should all be good about guarding against [link rot](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=link+rot). Everyone should feel empowered to drop a comment, edit in a link-referent's relevant summary with a good edit-comment, or even downvote-with-comment if you see a post that really *depends* on a link.

Comment: As a possible solution you can attempt to locate a copy of the missing page by entering the URL into the Internet Archive [Wayback Machine](https://www.archive.org/web/). I've had mixed results there, but the more popular the page. or site, was the better your odds.

Answer (score 3):

The forum situation has now (sort of) been resolved. Unfortunately, it is in a way that irreparably breaks all old links to content. What they've done is archived the old forum, so its accessible, but the links are all different.

What this means in practice is that we have a host of Savage Worlds questions and answers with broken links that need editing. The only way to find the correct links is going to be to search the archived forums [here](http://archive.pegforum.com/), which is laborious and will take some time. I will start gradually working my way through my answers to start with, but any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there no URL similarity that would let us deduce the archive URL?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie not that I could work out. The first thing I tried was replacing the root of the old address with archive.pegforum.com but that didn't seem to work. I might be missing something obvious though.....